# MySQL selecting duplicate name for 2 or more ids

Tags: mysql, sql

I have following table:

```
| id    | name   |
|-------|--------|
| 00001 | Item A |
| 00001 | Item A |
| 00002 | Item B |
| 00003 | Item C |
| 00004 | Item C |
```

What MySQL query I should use if I want to check if there's same name for 2 or more different ids? I have tried using `LEFT JOIN` and `UNION` in my queries, but I can't get it to work. So in this case, the query should return:

```
| id    | name   |
|-------|--------|
| 00003 | Item C |
| 00004 | Item C |
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what about Item A - this is also duplicate ?

Comment: No, it's not because the id is same. @amdixon

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to return the original rows, then you need to `join` something back to the original data:

```
select t.*
from t join
     (select name, count(distinct id) as cnt
      from t
      group by name
     ) tt
     on t.name = tt.name
where cnt >= 2;
```

If you just want the names, then the subquery is sufficient (with a `having` clause).

Answer (score 0):

Join the table with itself `ON` same `name` and different `id`.

**Query**

```
select t1.id,t1.name
from tbl1 t1
join tbl1 t2
on t1.id <> t2.id
and t1.name = t2.name;
```

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/69d72/1)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like this?

```
SELECT *
FROM table_name
GROUP BY name
HAVING count(DISTINCT id) > 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT name, COUNT(id) as cnt
FROM table
GROUP BY name
HAVING cnt > 1
```

Comment: Wouldn't that also count the ids from 'Item A' as 2?

Answer (score 0):

```
    SELECT distinct(t1.id) as id,t1.name
    FROM tbl1 t1
    JOIN tbl1 t2 ON t1.id=t2.id and t1.name = t2.name;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
select id, name from customers where name in
(select name from customers group by name having count(*) > 1)
```